# jQuery selectable with another event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

I am using the jQuery selectable on a table like this...

```
 var body=$("<tbody class='selectable'></tbody>")
 body.selectable({
     filter: 'td:not(:first-child)'
 });
 // this is the first column which is filteres out of the selectable
 $(".first-col").on('click',function(e){
      console.log("click for first column is here");
 });
```

I would like the first column to have a different callback function, but the click on the first column never gets called. Is it possible to do this? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help
V

Comment: why can't you attach a click event to '.selectable' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a known "bug" with selectable. You can set the distance option to anything other than 0 (default) to fix this but the best way is just to change your click even to mousedown (will work).

Example...

```
 $(".first-col").on('mousedown',function(e){
      console.log("click for first column is here");
 });
```